# rm -rf /* recovery - restoring deleted files from unknown folders

Tags: time-machine, restore

I accidentally typed

```
$ rm -rf /*
```

(backslash was NOT intended). Fortunately it was without `sudo` and I aborted it quickly. Nonetheless, it removed a number of files.

Most of things seems to work (it did uninstall and application or two).

As I don't want to restore all from Time Machine (a week old thing), how to check which system files were removed (and to restore them)?

Comment: I would use Time Machine and only choose to restore if file does not exist. (This is what TM is designed for) If really just system files I would get the combo update from Apple and apply that.

Comment: @Mark And how to restore removed files without changing existing files?

Comment: Time machine will ask if you want to overwrite files Anyway if they are system files then they won't have changed unless you applied an update - if the latter reapply the update

Comment: @Mark "Anyway if they are system files then they won't have changed unless you applied an update - if the latter reapply the update" - I am not sure if I understand you. I guess most systems files are not updated with each system update (think e.g. printer drivers or anything).

Comment: My comment was that system files won't have changed in the last week so use the Time Machine backup - or if they have then that was due to system update, if so rerun the system update

Comment: @Mark But how to make sure that other files won't get 'restored' to their old versions (e.g. all documents I have been working on, all other application configs, etc)?

Comment: Just do the system directories from Time Machine - or if reinstall the OS it won't touch documents